# Samsung Galaxy tab S3 not receiving power from otg y-cable

Tags: usb-on-the-go

Sorry to be a noob, but im not skilled enough to see if this question has already been answered.

Ive watched Youtube videos on how to connect an external HDD to my galaxy tab s3 using an otg y-cable.  The y-cable I bought from amazon for $6, it has a usb 3.0 female splitting to one micro usb male and one micro usb female.

The hard drive is recognized but no power is being supplied to my tablet via the y-cable.

i plug my samsung power cable into the micro usb female.  the HDD plugs into the 3.0 female and im using a micro usb to usb c adapter for the micro usb male end of the y-cable, as shown in videos.

can anyone provide advice or recommendations?

Thank you.

Comment: charging will not work. it is of the nature when switching between host or peripheral mode, the charge is for power the peripherals, not the host